# how many branches can i create using if statement?

Tags: pascal

how many branches can i create using if statement? is it limited?

Comment: ...and this is how to do it: http://privat.rejbrand.se/howtoaccept.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `IF` statement *always* has exactly two branches: one where the condition is `FALSE` and one where the condition is `TRUE`. A branching construct that has more than two branches is usually called `CASE` or `SWITCH`. In Pascal, it's `CASE`.

Comment: Of course, you can always nest your control structures, limited only by your ability to copy-and-paste, and the compilers memory limits.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not limited except by the storage capacity on your development system.

Comment: He did not say that he intends to compile his code, actually. I can put as many branches in my files as I want, the only limiting factor will be the storage capacity plus file system constraints :-)

Answer (score 1):

Always think towards a State/Strategy pattern before making a ton of branches on logic. Not sure your language of choice so I cant really help with concrete implementation, but you should be able to refactor any switch case or if comparable into a Key hooked to the correct value, and pull out the object/method/variable needed based on your key.

Comment: It's tagged `pascal` – does that tell you anything about the language in question? :-)

Comment: :P, an early morning it was today.

things to make you go... derp.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit actually, but as we know the numbers of code always effect the capacity of Memory, so RAM wich limit it.